# Measuring Degree of Product Differentiation/Market Segmentation

Tags: reference-request, industrial-organisation, empirical-methods, product-differentiation

In context of Hotelling location model, if firms are located at end points (maximal differentiation), then, except the customer(s) at the centre, all others have a strictly preferred seller.

Suppose we have data where we see final transactions between sellers and buyers. In data we can also observe location of consumer (some characteristic of buyer which I
hypothesize as the dimension of product differentiation) and which seller they have bought from. What we do not know is the location of sellers

From the distribution of consumers' location within each sellers sales, I wish to *measure* the extent to which sellers are differentiated.

In a way I am trying to capture to what extent the market is segmented. If, for example, there are no two sellers who have consumers from same location then market is perfectly segmented. Greater the share of consumers with common location among sellers lower the spread of firms in location space.

My attempt (Discrete location space): Think of each firm represented by a vector where each element is share of consumers from a particular type (kind of portfolio of seller). We have one vector each for each seller. Objective is to see how *orthogonal* these vectors are. Does this make sense?

I am looking for references from literature for this sort of measure. Any other suggestion is most welcome.